# Which is heads and tails?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In *Hunter x Hunter* the Phantom Troupe flip a coin from time to time to make decisions.

On one side is a spider and on the other, a web.

Here is the image of the coin:

[image]

Which is heads and which is tails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Phantom_Troupe#Coin_Tossing),

> The coin used is custom-made, the heads side sporting the group's signature twelve-legged spider, and the tails side depicting a spider's web.

An example is seen in **Chapter 92**, when Feitan and Nobunaga had a slight disagreement on what to do with Gon and Killua and settled it with a coin toss. Nobunaga won with a heads and the coin is then shown where the twelve-legged spider is facing up.